# Necesito extraer un dato de una lista desplegable y dar un dato en la misma sección

Tags: html, script

Necesito Seleccionar de una lista desplegable una provincia y desplegar un dato XXX Lista de Provincias y Cantidad de usuarios online y offline

```
<select name="provincia">
<option selected="selected" value="1">CABA</option>
<option value="2">Buenos Aires P</option>
<option value="3">Córdoba</option>
<option value="4">Jujuy</option>
<option value="5">Salta</option>
</select>      

      <li><a href="#">Status</a></li>
            <select name="Status">
<option value="1">TOTAL</option>
<option value="2">Online</option>
<option value="3">Offline</option>
</select> 

    </ul>
    <p>ONLINE 551</p>        
    <p>OFFLINE 37</p>
```